# How do I use the find statement in bash shell with multiple conditions for the filename

Tags: bash, shell

I need to display all of the files in the "final" directory and sub
directories that start with 2 underscore, followed by any number of any
characters, ending in a number, with the “.c” extension.

Can I get some help here? I can't figure it out that how do I use multiple conditions that would fulfill the requirements.

```
#!/bin/bash
fine . -type f -iname "__*"
find . -type f -iname "*.c"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the desired filename pattern correctly, this should work:

```
find . -type f -iname "__*[0-9].c"
```

This is pretty much a literal translation of your description into glob pattern syntax:

```
"__" (start with 2 underscore)
"*" (any number of any characters)
"[0-9]" (a number)
".c" (with the “.c” extension)
```

The only thing that doesn't quite correspond to your description is that this only looks for a single digit before the ".c", rather than a potentially-multi-digit number. But if there's more than one digit, the "*" will match all but the last, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If either condition is true:

```
find . -type f -iname '__*' -o -iname '*.c'
```

If both have to be true, use `-a` instead of `-o`:

```
find . -type f -iname '__*' -a -iname '*.c'
```

Of course, in that case it would be much more simple to just do

```
find . -type f -iname '__*.c'
```

Comment: Its running even if just one condition is true.. what if there isn't a .c file ? I want it not to run even if one condition is not fulfilling

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing that... do you want the result printed if *either* condition is met, or only if *both* conditions are met? If it has to be both, why not just do `find . -type f -iname '__*.c'`?  But, if the example were more complex and that wouldn't work, `find . -type f -iname '__*' -a -iname '*.c'`.

Comment: if both conditions are met

Comment: And how do we give a requirement which "followed by any number of any characters, ending in a number"

Comment: You'd probably have to use a regex for that… So for "starts with two underscores, followed by any number of characters followed by a number, then a dot and c", something like `find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/_[^/]*[0-9].*'` should do the trick.